# Error changing view perspective in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glm-math

I'm trying to change the perspective of my square in OpenGL but when I put some vectors to multiply with my position's vector the image disappears and don't know if I changed the perspective enough to make it disappear from the screen or it is a rendering problem which I think that is more probable

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aColor;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTex;

out vec3 color;

out vec2 texCoord;

//uniform float scale;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = proj * view * model * vec4(position, 1.0);
    color = aColor;
    texCoord = aTex;
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

out vec4 FragColor;

in vec3 color;

in vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2D tex0;

void main()
{
 FragColor = texture(tex0, texCoord);
}
```

Part of the program with the implementation:

```
while (true)
  {
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
    {
      if (SDL_QUIT == windowEvent.type)
      {
        break;
      }
    }
    //Cor do background
    glClearColor(0.05f, 0.57f, 0.38f, 1.0f);
    //Limpa o buffer e o atribui uma nova cor
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Ativa o Programa Shader designado
    shaderProgram.Activate(shaderProgram);

    mat4 model = {1.f};
    mat4 view = {1.f};
    mat4 proj = {1.f};

    glm_translate(view, (vec3){0.f, -0.5f, -2.f});
    glm_perspective(glm_rad(45.f), (float)(SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT), 0.1f, 100.f, proj);
    int modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.id, "model");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (float *)model);
    int viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.id, "view");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (float *)view);
    int projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram.id, "proj");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, (float *)proj);

    //Atribui um valor uniforme podendo aumentar ou reduzir o objeto renderizado
    glUniform1f(uniID, 0.5);
    //Liga a textura para aparecer na renderização
    imagem.Bind(imagem);
    //Vincula o VAO ao OpenGL para ser usado
    vao1.Bind(vao1);
    //Desenha o elemento
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glEnd();
    //update the window
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
  }
```

Comment: oi Eduardo, my guess is that "glm_translate".... you are translating -2 in Z... that's too far...

Comment: I was following a tutorial and the guy uses these values. I also tried to reduce the z value, but I still get no image. I'm thinking the problem is related to vertex shader or in the passing parameters, but I really don't know

Comment: there are more strange things... glEnd() should not be necessary here

Comment: also... try `(proj * view * model) * vec4(position, 1.0);` [with parenthesis]

Comment: I deleted the glEnd() and tried to modify the vertex shader putting the parentheses still get the only the screen without the image, tomorrow I'll try to change the library that works with the matrices to see if change something

Comment: Your language is C++ not C. Why do you use "cglm" instead of [glm](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using is C++ and [glm](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/index.html), then `glm::mat4 model(1.0f);` constructs an identity matrix.

If you are using [cglm](https://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) then `mat4 model = {1.f};` does not initialize an identity matrix. `mat4` is a structure, but not a class with a constructor.

You have to use [`glm_mat4_identity`](https://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mat4.html#c.glm_mat4_identity):

<s>`mat4 model = {1.f};`</s>
<s>`mat4 view = {1.f};`</s>
<s>`mat4 proj = {1.f};`</s>

```c
mat4 model, view, proj;
glm_mat4_identity(model); 
glm_mat4_identity(view);
glm_mat4_identity(proj);
```

Comment: Actually, I'm using pure  C to follow the tutorial as a kind of self-challenge and I heard that it can be faster than c++, I used the wrong tag on the question and I'll fix it. Your answer got helped me a lot, it got right. Thank you very much, I spend too many hours on this issue since yesterday, I was almost giving up and migrating everything to c++